# My Admob Account disabled for "Invalid Activity"

Tags: admob

My Admob account got disabled on 14 April 2016 for reason "Invalid Activity".
I have multiple android applications and was using Admob in all my apps.

I did not click on my ads and also not paid/motivated anyone to do so.

I made the appeal giving all the reasons.

Although I have already switched to other Ad Network, But I am still waiting for response.

Will they respond that whether the account will be enabled or it will remain disabled ? Or they respond only if account is re enabled ?

Comment: To which ad network you switched? do you know any better ad network other than admob?

Answer (score 0):

My account also get disabled. Previous time when i get invalid activity they suspended my account for one month. Google will send a mail to you if your account re enabled. Otherwise no response from those guys. I have been waiting for 2 months, since then no response.

Answer (score 0):

"I did not click on my ads and also not paid/motivated anyone to do so." - that's good, but sometimes it happens, that wrong ad placement can lead to fraud like clicks and so on. As I know showing ads at app launch equals ban. AdMob may not answer, it's a kind of lottery. Still I'd advice to contact them and ask about which definitely doesn't correspond to their terms. Good luck with it)

Answer (score 0):

Nope Friend There are no chance for re enable if it disable permanently As Per My experience google will not going to enable your account if its permanently terminate your admob account as well not going to give you the exact reason or problem for 'invalid activity'.